# Testing values returned from resolve object in ui-router state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, karma-jasmine

I have a UI-router state with some resolves, and I now want to test the output of these resolves, but I have no idea how to get access to the results.

I tried mocking the controller and check the arguments passed into it, but I seem to be unable to do this.

route:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  views: {
    content: {
      controller: 'HomeCtrl as vm',
      template: ''
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    myresolve: function() { return 'cool!'; }
  }
});
```

test:

```
$state.go('home');
$rootScope.$apply();

expect(???).toEqual('cool!');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller HomeCtrl inject myresolve :

```
angular.module(...).controlle('HomeCtrl', function(myresolve){
    expect(myresolve).toEqual('cool!');
});
```

cf : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

or : https://scotch.io/tutorials/making-skinny-angularjs-controllers#use-ui-router-to-state-the-obvious-